# .NET get mouse button state and position in and empty project

Tags: .net, vb.net, keyboard, mouse

how do I get the position (not relative to anything) and button states for the mouse in an empty project (no forms, nothing). For a key I could use:

```
Imports System.Windows.Input

If IsKeyDown(Key.A) Then

End If
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you writing windows add-on? There are always windows API that you can use.

Comment: You probably are looking at something like http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/

Comment: @DonA It's not malicious :)

Comment: If the project has `no forms, nothing` then how do you write code?

Comment: You can't get the position "not relative to anything". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Center_of_the_Universe

Comment: @DonA It's and empty project    `Imports System.Threading    Class Class1    Shared Sub Main()    While True    Thread.Sleep(1)    End While    End Sub    End Class`

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg England, XV'th century. I, Lord Hector Allembick, hereby declare, that this feeble peasant, by the name of Fraser Of Smégé, has the nerve to propose his radical idea in thy lordship's presence. His hideous and grotesque conception is that the earth revolves around the sun. Everything in this universe revolves around the earth. These are dark days, and the storm clouds gather around us, but I pledge, as your leader, to take you safely through to a better world. Today the post office, tomorrow the world. Muhahhahaha. **FRASER SHALL BE TAKEN TO THE LONDON GAOL TOMORROW**